# Aerospike Delete Record in list if element of bin known

Tags: php, aerospike

I have a set that have three bins ( PK, cat_id and data ). List index is applied on cat_id . I am able to select record by query:

```
SELECT * FROM test.myset IN LIST where cat_id = '1'
```

It is working fine for me. Now I need to delete this record by same condition. But as I have read that PK is necessary to delete any record . In my case i have cat_id to delete this record.

Help me to delete this record by using bin element not PK. I am using PHP for it. AQL also work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use an asynchronous background query that applies a tiny ([record UDF](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/record_udf.html)) Lua function to every record matched by that query's predicate. In the PHP client, you'd use the [queryApply()](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-php/blob/master/doc/aerospike_queryapply.md) method for this.

This Lua function simply says 'die':

```
function del_rec(rec)
    aerospike:remove(rec)
end
```

I used the [Lua UDF API reference](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/api_reference.html) for this 'complex' function, mainly the [aerospike object](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/api/aerospike.html) reference. If you wanted to do more logic, like check on other bins, you'd be using the [record](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/api/record.html) methods. There's more info on [UDFs](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/udf.html) and [developing Record UDFs](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/developing_record_udfs.html) at the Aerospike website.

Once you [register UDF module](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/udf_management.html) (the file containing this function) with the cluster, you can call it from your PHP code:

```
$where = Aerospike::predicateContains("cat_id", Aerospike::INDEX_TYPE_LIST, 1);
$status = $client->queryApply("test", "mytest", $where, "my_udfs", "del_rec", [], $job_id);
if ($status === Aerospike::OK) {
    var_dump("The background job ID is $job_id");
} else {
    echo "An error occured while initiating the background query [{$client->errorno()}] ".$client->error();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Ronen . You are awesome . Also i want to know about UDF performance . I can first select PK by using Aerospike::INDEX_TYPE_LIST  and after will delete record by using that PK . So What is better UDF or first select than delete . And also Can you please tell me how much concurrent (update/delete/add)  request  aerospike can handle if ram is assigned to 1 GB ? It will be very beneficial for me .

Comment: UDFs take more memory (must have a Lua instance) and are slower than a native operation. They don't parallelize as well as native key-value operations do. If you need very low latency for an operation, or very high concurrency you probably shouldn't use a UDF. For your delete example  you can easily use the record UDF attached to a background scan or query, because it's fine to do it asynchronously.